# Non-separable, higher-order generalized cosine windows in 2D for images

Tags: window-functions, window, parametric-eq

[Higher-order generalized cosine windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Higher-order_generalized_cosine_windows) define a useful parametric family of windows functions, embedding Hamming, Hann, Blackman, Nutall, etc.:
$$w(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{K} a_k\; \cos\left( \frac{2 \pi k n}{N} \right)$$
Are there non-separable 2D similar forms, i.e. not a tensor product of the 1D form, usable on the standard rectangular lattice (excluding designs such as in [Multidimensional windows over arbitrary lattices and their application to FIR filter design](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICASSP.1996.547762))?

Comment: Why do you need them to be "non-separable"? What are the properties of the 1D generalized cos windows that you're after?

Comment: I first wanted to exclude the mere tensor product of 1D windows. Plus, non-separable windows, used for tappering or modulation in filter banks, can be more appropriate in dealing with directions in images. I would like to have both clean sample tappering (zeroing) on the border of the image, and an easy discrete Fourier implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form:

$$w(x, y) = \sum_{j = -K}^{K}\sum_{k = -K}^{K} a_{|j|,|k|}\; \cos(\pi jx + \pi ky),$$

where:

$$a_{j,k} = a_{k,j},\\
\sum_{j = -K}^{K}\sum_{k = -K}^{K} a_{|j|,|k|} = 1,\\
x \in -1..1,\\
y \in -1..1$$

yields window functions that are 2D similar. Window functions of that form are not generally separable, but some of them are, for example:

$$w(x, y) = \frac{\cos(\pi x - \pi y)}{8} + \frac{\cos(\pi x + \pi y)}{8} + \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{4} + \frac{\cos(\pi y)}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\\
= \left(\frac{\cos\left(\pi x\right)}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\cos\left(\pi y\right)}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

[image: Separable window function]

For this window function, if the balance between the zero-frequency term and the higher terms is altered (as in going from Hann to Hamming), separability breaks.

Comment: In my earlier answer I argued that it is difficult to make all four boundaries go to zero value, but when I tried a numerical optimization of the window function it turned out that the boundaries can go to exactly zero with only a few cosine terms. So I deleted that false answer.